# Why does $TdS = d(TS)$ for constant T?

Tags: calculus

For an isothermal process, (T remains constant) we can say that $Tds = d(TS)$.

How can this be correct?  Isn't $d(TS) = 0$ if T is constant?

Comment: If $a$ is a constant, then (just thinking of ordinary derivatives here), $\dfrac{d}{dx} a = 0$, but of course $\dfrac{d}{dx} (a f(x)) = a f'(x)$, not $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ d(TS)=TdS+SdT$

So if $\ T$ is constant, you have $\ dT=0$ and the result follows

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is constant you have $dT=0$ and therefore $d(TS) = TdS + SdT = TdS$

Answer (score 1):

Because $$\frac{d(Ts)}{ds}=T.$$